# When I insert new row in the sqliteDB in Android then it will always taking its previous row in the DB?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I insert new row in the sqliteDB in Android then it will always taking its previous row in the DB?

**Model Classes:**

ModelProducts:

```
public class ModelProducts {
private String prodId;
private String prodName;
private String prodDesc;
private String prodPrice;


public ModelProducts() {
super();
}

public ModelProducts(String prodId, String prodName, String prodDesc, String prodPrice) {
this.prodId = prodId;
this.prodName = prodName;
this.prodDesc = prodDesc;
this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
}

public ModelProducts(String prodId, String prodName, String prodPrice){

this.prodId = prodId;
this.prodName = prodName;
this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
}

public String getProdId() {
return prodId;
}

public String getProdName() {
return prodName;
}

public String getProdDesc() {
return prodDesc;
}

public String getProdPrice() {
return prodPrice;
}

public void setProdId(String prodId) {
this.prodId = prodId;
}

public void setProdName(String prodName) {
this.prodName = prodName;
}

public void setProdDesc(String prodDesc) {
this.prodDesc = prodDesc;
}

public void setProdPrice(String prodPrice) {
this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
}

}
```

ModelCartItem:

```
public class ModelCartItem {

private ModelProducts product;
private int productQuantity;

public ModelCartItem() {
    super();
}

public ModelProducts getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public int getProductQuantity() {
    return productQuantity;
}

public void setProduct(ModelProducts product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public void setProductQuantity(int productQuantity) {
    this.productQuantity = productQuantity;
}

}
```

In the DatabaseHelper class

```
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "shoppingCart";

 // Table Names
 private static final String TABLE_CART = "cart";


 //CART Table - column names
 private static final String KEY_PRODID = "prod_id";
 private static final String KEY_PROD_NAME = "prod_name";
 private static final String KEY_PROD_PRICE = "prod_price";
 private static final String KEY_PROD_QUANTITY = "prod_quantity";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
```

Create Table:

```
// Cart table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CART = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CART
            + "(" + KEY_PRODID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," 
            + KEY_PROD_NAME + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_PROD_PRICE + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_PROD_QUANTITY + " TEXT"
            + ")";  
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // creating required tables
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CART);
}
```

Insert:

```
 public void addtoCart(ModelCartItem item, int productQuantity) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PRODID, item.getProduct().getProdId());
    values.put(KEY_PROD_NAME, item.getProduct().getProdName());
    values.put(KEY_PROD_PRICE, item.getProduct().getProdPrice());
    values.put(KEY_PROD_QUANTITY, item.getProductQuantity());

    // insert row
    db.insert(TABLE_CART, null, values);

    db.close();


}
```

When i Add the Item using below code in the Activity one i.e. ProductActivity  Where datamodel is object of ModelProducts class and the data in the ModelProducts class is come from onclick of button.

In this Activity i make a object of Db helper in the onCreate() method

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper  = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

And this is the code for inserting a new row in the DB in the onCreate() method

```
 Log.d("TAG", "Product Id: "+ dataModel.getProdId());
                  Log.d(TAG, "Product Name: " + dataModel.getProdName());
                  Log.d(TAG, "Product Description: " + dataModel.getProdDesc());
                  Log.d(TAG, "Product Price: " + dataModel.getProdPrice());
int productQuantity = 1;
                      ModelCartItem item = new ModelCartItem();
                      item.setProduct(dataModel);
                      item.setProductQuantity(productQuantity);

                      databaseHelper.addtoCart(item, productQuantity);
```

After that i want to retrieve all added data into another activity i.e. BasketActivity so problem is that last inserted row value is come in the list item of row.
In the Basket Activity on the onCreate() method following code is run

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basket);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewProduct);
    imagebtnCategory = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebtnCategory);

    ArrayList<ModelCartItem>arrayList3 = databaseHelper.getAllCartItem();

    for(ModelCartItem cartItem: arrayList3){

        Log.d("ID product: ", cartItem.getProduct().getProdId());
        Log.d("Name product: ", cartItem.getProduct().getProdName());
        Log.d("Price product: ", cartItem.getProduct().getProdPrice());
        Log.d("Quantity product: ", ""+cartItem.getProductQuantity());
    }
 }
```

This is method for getting all item from DB

```
public ArrayList<ModelCartItem> getAllCartItem() {
    ModelProducts modelProducts = new ModelProducts();
    ModelCartItem cartItem = new ModelCartItem();
    ArrayList<ModelCartItem> todos = new ArrayList<ModelCartItem>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CART;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            modelProducts.setProdId((c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODID)))));
            modelProducts.setProdName((c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROD_NAME)))));
            modelProducts.setProdPrice((c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROD_PRICE)))));

            cartItem.setProduct(modelProducts);
            cartItem.setProductQuantity(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROD_QUANTITY))));

            // adding to cartItem list
            todos.add(cartItem);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return todos;
}
```

Input for that is:
Value for Id 279 is

```
Product Name is Mafalde ai calamari,
Product Price is 9.00
Quantity is 1
```

And Value for Id 310 is

```
Product Name is Italiano,
Product Price is 5.00
Quantity is 2
```

Then Output will be come like that in the LogCat:

```
ID Product: 279
Name Product: Mafalde ai calamari
Price Product: 9.00 
Quantity product: 1


ID Product: 279
Name Product: Mafalde ai calamari
Price Product: 9.00 
Quantity product: 1
```

Here, Value for id 279 is repeated two time but I given input as id 279 and 310.

Finally, my question is that I want all those item which is present into above Arraylist? And also item which is not repeated as shown above Output?

I want output like that

```
ID Product: 279
Name Product: Mafalde ai calamari
Price Product: 9.00 
Quantity product: 1


ID Product: 310
Name Product: Italiano
Price Product: 5.00 
Quantity product: 2
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Too much code to read, but reading the problem at bottom: post your `getAllCartItem()`

Comment: I added the getAllCartItem() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getAllCartItem()`, move the

```
ModelProducts modelProducts = new ModelProducts();
ModelCartItem cartItem = new ModelCartItem();
```

inside the `do`-`while` loop so that new model objects are created for each row, instead of the previous ones being reused.

Comment: One more question, I want to ask to you 
if i add new row in the getAllCartItem() then if this row is already exist in that Arraylist.
Then how can i find it using code.

Comment: Don't store duplicates in the database in the first place.

Comment: I appreciate you point, but i want to add if() condition for that then what code i wright for that.
Please give me coding e.g. for that.